# Unexpected Behavior of Regex in Perl with Lookahead/Lookbehind

Tags: regex, perl

On https://regexr.com/67r1h using the PCRE engine my regex is correctly matching all un-escaped double quote characters.

```
/(?<!^|,|(?<!^|,)")"(?!,|$|"(?!,|$))/gm
```

test data:

```plaintext
one,"George "Georgie"","Washington"
""two"",""Johnny" John","Adams"
"""three""","""Tommy"" Thomas ""BigT""","Jefferson"
"four","Sinead","O"Connor"
```

The expected output is that lines 1, 2, and 4 match. Line 3 should not match because all double quotes are either quoted identifiers for the field or properly escaped double quotes.

However, when executing the following command in Bash using perl v5.30 and v5.34, I do not get any matches:

```
echo 'one,"George "Georgie"","Washington"' | perl -ne '/(?<!^|,|(?<!^|,)")"(?!,|$|"(?!,|$))/gm && print'
```

output:

```
Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!^|,|(?<!^|,)")"(?!,|$|"(?!,|$)) <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

I'm at a loss as to why perl will not match this regex. Is there something wrong in my bash command or in my regex? Is the PCRE implementation able to handle nested lookahead/behinds while the perl implementation is not able to?

Comment: Not the problem but that /g is wrong. `if (//g)` makes no sense and can give the wrong result in very puzzling ways

Comment: Note that Perl doesn't use PCRE, an independent library inspired by Perl.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: A lookbehind has to be a fixed length. The lookbehind matches either `^` (length=0), `,` (length=1), or either of those followed by `"` (lengh = 1 or 2).

Comment: I'm also not so sure about nesting negative lookbehinds.

Comment: @Barmar You appear to have misread the message. The lookbehind doesn't need to be fixed length. Quite the opposite, it says it can be a variable length, though this is an experimental feature.

Comment: @ikegami YOu're right, I misread. I didn't know there was a plan to relax that restriction. I'm still unsure about nesting them, though.

Comment: @Barmar Should not be a problem `a(?=b(?!c))` should and does work fine

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, your domain knowledge on this seems more expert than mine. Please let me know if I can provide any further clarification of my use case that can help you answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Perl, probably in the experimental variable lookbehind feature.

Simpler case:

```sh
$ echo ' "G' | perl -M5.010 -ne'say /(?<!^|,|(?<!^|,)")"(?!,|$|"(?!,|$))/ || 0'
Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!^|,|(?<!^|,)")"(?!,|$|"(?!,|$)) <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
0
```

Tested using the latest version (5.34.0).

Comment: Also happens with 5.34.0. Gotta go, but will see about creating a ticket tomorrow.